# Order independent transparency

Tags: 3d, webgl

I've have a problem.

I have allot of static vertices around a sphere - drawing them as Points

I'm drawing a texture with transparency on each. E.g. Letters.

Point size is relatively big so I will see the texture.

The user can change the camera angle, roll, tilt and move around the globe.

The problem is that when a point is being drawn after other points it might be not rendered because of depth test. But because of my transparency texture, it is preventing the points from being drawn properly.

For ex.

[image]

The White 'Text' is a 4 vertices word that is drawn first.

The Red 'Text' is also 4 vertices word that is drawn second.

Because of the depth test the red is no fully drawn.

Sorting is not efficient here for every frame rendered due too massive amount of vertices.

I've done some research about it and I came across the OIT - Order independent transparency. Found many articles and less examples.

But this is not the issue.

I'm trying to understand the logic behind it. But I just not managing: (
I'm familiar with blending, textures, fbo, depth,.

I realize that there are some different algorithms for making it work, some single pass and some multi pass

Can anyone explain this it in a "simple" way? And is it going to help me here?

Comment: "*Can anyone explain this it in a "simple" way?*" Explain what in a simple way? Your problem is that you're using blending and depth testing.

Comment: Explain the OIT.. And how is it solving it

Comment: OIT means exactly what it says: order independent transparency. Transparency that works independently of rendering order. OIT is not a thing; it is not something you flip on. It is an *effect*. There are numerous techniques for *achieving* OIT, just as there are numerous techniques for achieving bloom, secular reflection, tone mapping, etc. None of the OIT techniques would be described as "simple".

Comment: Yes, I've read about them.. and this is why i didn't manage to understand , even not one. So i post this question hope that i'm missing some simple thing that will make me understand all.

Comment: @RazizaO: You're not missing something simple. OIT is a really hard problem that's still lacks a satisfying general solution. OIT is subject of active computer science research and some of the top people in the field are dedicating their time to it. Sorting on the other hand *is* a solved problem and simple to use implementations of the efficient algorithms exist.

Comment: Is it going to solve my problem here ? Technically, My letters themselves are not transparent. Is it good direction to dig into ? Let's say, in a year - when i will understand it :) i will see what i'm expecting ? or this is only for transparency colors?

Comment: @RazizaO: From the images given, it is not even clear if you actually need transparency at all, or if you can get away with discarding the "background" fragments of your texture (similiar to the alpha test in legacy GL).

Comment: I've tried to discard in the f-shader but it is does not look good - It is looked cut. because i had to decide from which alpha to discard, and i tried allot.. It is just thinning my text letters or it is adding some pixels around them that still blocking the texts behind (as expected) either way, does not look nice. sometimes also the text is smaller and it is more visible

Comment: You can try this, its a compromise, and it works allright. Might not be good enough for text, but its simple to implement so you can test that yourself. http://blog.wolfire.com/2009/02/rendering-plants-with-smooth-edges/

Answer (score 0):

I known this is old, but anyway...
You should seen [if OIT is really necessary](http://www.openglsuperbible.com/2013/08/20/is-order-independent-transparency-really-necessary/) for what you want to do. If you just want to draw partially transparent billboarded texts over an opaque background, you may get away with sorting the billboards back-to-front every frame and render using "standard" alpha-blending (glBlendEquation(GL_FUNC_ADD) and glBlendFunc(GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL_SRC_ALPHA)). Also turn off depth writes (glDepthMask(GL_FALSE)) when rendering the transparent objects, but keep the depth test enabled (glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)).

Comment: This cause as expected - Items that suppose to be in the front of others are drawn in the back of them just because there are first in the buffer